# Casting an Object to an Interface

Tags: java, interface, casting

i have the following Classes and interfaces:

```
public interface if1 {}
public class ifTest implements if1 {}

public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          //why does the following cast not work (Compiler error)  
          ifTest var3 = (if1) new ifTest();
     }
}
```

Why does this cast not work? I get the following compile error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from if1 to ifTest"

Comment: The cast works fine, it's the assignment that doesn't work.

Comment: Your class name should begin with capital letter (or) it must begin with an upper case letter

Comment: Why? Because the ifTest Variable can't hold a reference to if1? Is there than any way, that I can assign an interface to a object-variable?

Comment: The assignment fails because an object referenced by a variable of type `if1` is not necessarily of type `ifTest`. It could be some other subclass of `if1`. The compiler does not necessarily know the object type. In some cases, it's not known until run-time, and can vary between calls.

Comment: @Evalsha that was just a quick test man

Comment: @Andy Thomas thanks, thought so. So in the most cases, I won't be able to assign a interface-type reference to a object-type variable right?

Comment: Sure you can. You can do `if1 var = new ifTest()`. The compiler knows that every `ifTest` is-a `if1`. You can always assign to a less-specific type higher in the inheritance hierarchy. Assigning to a more-specific or unrelated reference type requires casting.

Comment: @vogs please follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Yeah of course this works because the variable is of an interface-type, I am aware of that. Thanks!
But I can't think of a suitable example where I can assign an interface-type to a variable of an class-type

Comment: Sorry, I misread your second comment back. Right. If you have a value whose type is an interface, assigning it to a variable of class type would require explicit down-casting. Usually this is preceded by an `instanceof` check. Ideally, it's avoided entirely, so that you can use the same code for multiple types.

Comment: You can do it with a downcast, accepting the risk of a `ClassCastException`. Your compilation error was due to the lack of a narrowing conversion cast in `ifTest var3 = (if1) new ifTest();`. You would have needed `ifTest var3 = (ifTest) (if1) new ifTest();`. (And do spell types with an initial upper-case letter!)

Comment: Why are we even doing an explicit downcast? An object can always be assigned to any of its parent classes without explicit cast if i'm not wrong ... ?

Comment: @rollback - Because it's not being assigned to a parent class. It's assigning downward from an interface type to one particular class that implements that interface type.

Comment: @AndyThomas I know, but what he actually wants to do is assigning `new ifTest()` to `if1 var3` (`if1 var3 = new ifTest();`) which wouldn't need an explicit cast at all

Comment: @rollback - The OP's code is `ifTest var3` -- not `if1 var3`.

Comment: @AndyThomas I know, but thats not what He wanted to do

Comment: @rollback - Your speculation does seem to take into account the OP's comments above. Further discussion of this speculation can be done without me.

Comment: @AndyThomas exactly, when reading this question I just remembered that I've seen explicit downcasting very often. That's why I wrote "we" and not "you" in my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance denotes an `is-a` relationship. Any object of `IfTest` *is-an* `If1`. However, a reference of type `If1` does **not necessarily** refer to an object of type `IfTest`.

In a textbook scenario, any `Dog` is an `Animal` but any `Animal` is not a `Dog` (it might be a zebra, elephant, deer, etc).

Casting takes the form:

```
A a = (B) c;
```

There are 2 steps involved:

1. You have any object `c` that is cast to type `B`.
2. That instance of `B` is then assigned to variable `a` (where `A` is a type that must be either equal to `B` or a super class of `B` for the compiler to be happy and for no `ClassCastExceptions` to occur at runtime.

Continuing the animal metaphor, you are casting `Dog` to an `Animal` in step 1, but then trying to assign that instance of an `Animal` to a variable of type `Dog`, which the compiler knows is not allowed.

The following would work because it casts `IfTest` to `If1` and then assigning that `If1` to `IfTest`.

```
if1 var3 = (if1) new ifTest();
```

**EDIT** As Lew points out in his comment below, this is what is referred to as a widening cast (because it goes from a specific type to a more generic, "wider" type. In this instance, the cast is not necessary because the compiler knows all references to objects of type `IfTest` by definition are also `If1`.

A more practical example would be if you had a reference to the interface and wanted to cast it to a `IfTest`. In this case, it's a "narrowing" cast because you're going from the generic type to a more specific, "narrower" type.

```
if1 var1 = (if1) new ifTest();
if (var1 instanceOf ifTest) {
    ifTest var2 = (ifTest) var1;
}
```

Note the use of the `instanceof` to to ensure that `var1` is in fact an instance of `IfTest`. While we know it is, in a real-world application `If1` might have multiple subtypes so this will not always be true. The check prevents the cast from throwing a run-time `ClassCassException`.

**TLDR**: The important thing to know is what is inside the parenthesis must be a type the compiler knows can be assigned to the variable being assigned to.

Comment: You show a widening cast, but the OP wants to know about narrowing casts. So you didn't answer the question.

Comment: He wanted to know why his cast didn't work so I went for a broader explanation of how casting works. I can add an example of a narrowing cast but I didn't think it helped answer his question of why.

Answer (score -2):

Here you are trying to instantiate an interface. An interface is just like a template or something similar to a contract - the class which implements the interface must obey the contract and provide implementation of the methods.

Comment: The OP is instantiating a *class*. Check the code: `new ifTest()` creates a new object of type `class ifTest`.

Comment: @AndyThomas yeah you are right - object creation is done for the class - but after that it is casted to interface type - so in the eyes of compiler it would be treated as an instance for an interface

Comment: The variable of interface type is a *reference* to an object of the class type. The interface itself is not instantiated, ever.

Comment: An interface is not a "dummy entity", it establishes type. Not only is there "no point" to direct instantiation of an interface, it's impossible. Classes don't necessarily have to implement every method in an interface; they can leave some or all of the `abstract` methods as `abstract` in the class. Interfaces can hold more than just declarations; they can contain (static) nested types, other static members, and `default` (orchestration) methods. This answer is incorrect and incomplete.

Comment: @LewBloch A class which implements an interface should implement all the method which an interface holds - it can leave the abstract methods with empty blocks.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: A class can be abstract, and if an abstract class implements an interface it inherits the methods as abstract methods already. It need not override any of them.

Comment: yeah you are right @LewBloch... This could be with `abstract` class.. But here his class is not abstract - so, he has to implement all the methods in the interface which he is going to implement...

Comment: After the edit, this answer still refers to instantiating an interface, and does not address the OP's question.